# OS X - El Capitan - How To Remove unused services from "Services" context menu

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, services, osx-el-capitan

I would like to remove entries from the `Keyboard_Services_list` (`Sys Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services`) because they are either obsolete or unused. Indeed some entries are zombie entries because the referred application was uninstalled.

[[image: [1]]

[image]

Here `Mailplane 3` and `Prizmo` Apps were removed months ago.

What I would like is also a command line approach to the solution in order to understand how the App are registering the services, but of course a more visual approach (GUI) is also welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Onyx, first tab 'Maintenance' & make sure LaunchServices is selected.

There's other ways to clean LaunchServices, but it's good to run Onyx anyway if you need to clean that up.

Comment: thanks this helped and sorry for responding so late. Is there any command line option to rebuild the LaunchServices DB ?